# How to add dynamic textview in recycler view adapter?

Tags: android-recyclerview, multi-select, dynamic-view

I want to add dynamic textview in recyclerview adapeter when the item is selected. But the dynamic view is add in another view and when i scroll the recyclerview dynamically created view is changed every time in that view. This is my adapter class

```
public class MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter SelectableAdapter<MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static List<Ingredient> mArrayList;
private static Context mContext;
private ViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener;

static ImageView add_img;
static ImageView remove_img;
static TextView textView_count;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
static boolean flag = false;
static HashMap<String,TextView> mTextViewList = new HashMap<>();
private ViewHolder mViewHolder;

public MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter (Context context, List<Ingredient> arrayList, ViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.mArrayList = arrayList;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

// Create new views
@Override
public MultiSelectRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {

    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.cardview_toppings, null);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView,clickListener);
    this.mViewHolder = viewHolder;

    return viewHolder;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    if(isSelected(position))
    {
        Ion.with(mContext).load(mArrayList.get(position).getThumbnail()).withBitmap().asBitmap()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, Bitmap result) {
                        viewHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(result);
                    }
                });

        viewHolder.textView.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getIngredient_name());

        viewHolder.textView_count.getId();

        for (Map.Entry<String, TextView> entry : mTextViewList.entrySet()) {
              entry.getValue().setVisibility(isSelected(position) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            entry.getValue().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.badge_circle);
        }

    }else {
        Ion.with(mContext).load(mArrayList.get(position).getThumbnail()).withBitmap().asBitmap()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, Bitmap result) {
                        viewHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(result);
                    }
                });

        viewHolder.textView.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getIngredient_name());
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mArrayList.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener,View.OnLongClickListener  {
        public TextView tvName;
        private ClickListener listener;
        private final View selectedOverlay;

        public ImageView thumbnail;
        public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
        public TextView textView;
        public RelativeLayout dynamic_relativeLayout;
        public TextView textView_count;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView, ClickListener listener) {
            super(itemLayoutView);

            this.listener = listener;

            tvName = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_name);
            selectedOverlay = (View) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.selected_overlay);

            thumbnail = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            textView = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_name);
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_relative);
            dynamic_relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_layout);

            textView_count = new TextView(mContext);


            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);

            itemLayoutView.setOnLongClickListener (this);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (listener != null) {

                flag = true;
            setImagePerview(mArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition ()).getPreview(), mContext);
        int id = View.generateViewId();

        textView_count.setId(id);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_text = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
        params_text.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        textView_count.setLayoutParams(params_text);
        textView_count.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.badge_circle);
        textView_count.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        mTextViewList.put(String.valueOf(id),textView_count);
        relativeLayout.addView(textView_count);

                listener.onItemClicked(getAdapterPosition ());

            }
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick (View view) {
            if (listener != null) {
                return listener.onItemLongClicked(getAdapterPosition ());
            }
            return false;
        }

        public interface ClickListener {
            public void onItemClicked(int position);

            public boolean onItemLongClicked(int position);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this is a common issues as you need to sync access to the holder. There are a few quite good libraries to handle this and other cases of bitmap caching, reusing, pooling.
```

you can use glide for local and network images:

```
   **Glide.with(context).load(items.get(i).getImage()).into(viewHolder.image);**
```

or for only network images Volley or jus swithing to their NetworkImageView widget and then in the adapter:

```
**image.setImageUrl(items.get(i).getImage(), imageLoader);**
```

These may use different approaches but they all know what to do